# Bordeaux-Threads: how to kill a thread?

Tags: multithreading, lisp, common-lisp

I only found how to kill a thread that I have assigned to a variable:
`(setf *foo* (bt:make-thread (lambda () (loop)) :name "Foo2"))` --> `(bt:destroy-thread *foo*)`

How can I kill just any thread that I can see with `(bt:all-threads)`:
`(bt:make-thread (lambda () (loop)) :name "Foo")` --> ?

Comment: In code (as opposed to debugging and/or in the REPL), you should notify the thread to exit gracefully instead of killing it.

Comment: Thank you! I asked because there is a part about [killing threads](http://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/process.html#emergency) in the Common Lisp Cookbook and I am trying to port that chapter from Lispworks-specific code to Bordeaux-Threads. I know killing is just a last resort, but maybe I should add that to the document.

Comment: @Pascal `(defun find-thread-from-name (name) (find name (bt:all-threads) :key #'bt:thread-name :test #'string=))` may come in handy.

Comment: Remember that it's almost impossible to safely kill a thread since you may leave data in an inconsistent state. The best solution is to somehow notify the thread that it needs to terminate and then let it exit by itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can kill any thread. There is nothing special about it. If you get a list of threads, just get the thread you want to kill and pass it to the function.

The function `destroy-thread` does not see a variable. Since it is a function, Lisp uses the usual evaluation rules. It gets passed a thread. The thread just happens to be the value of a variable in your example.

It could be the value of a function call:

```
(defun my-thread ()
  *foo*)

(bt:destroy-thread (my-thread))
```

or even part of a data structure, for example a list:

```
(defun my-thread ()
  (list 1 *foo* 3))

(bt:destroy-thread (second (my-thread)))
```

A thread is just another object.

If you get a list of threads, then you need to identify the correct thread. For example by looking at the name of the thread.

Comment: Thank you! I was sure I had tried `(bt:destroy-thread #<PROCESS Foo(115) [Active] #x30200148622D>)`, but I was obviously mistaken.

Comment: @Pascal You can't type that as input. Anything which looks like #<foo ... ... some-id> is an unreadable object. It's printed for an object, but it can't be read back. You need to access the data structure and pass the result.

Comment: Copying the text worked once just after reading your answer, but I am not sure what it depends on. The time it worked, its color stayed red like in the output of `(bt:all-threads)`, so I guess it was the object and not just the text. Anyway, I am not going to pursue this. But I am glad I did not just dream that I tried that without success.

Comment: @Pascal: That's just some magic from your IDE (Slime, I guess).

Comment: @Rainer, I'm seeing that the thread is quite alive and well after calling destroy-thread on it. It takes a fraction of a second for it to die a beautiful death. Example code (better copy paste it in emacs):
 `(let ((thread (bt:make-thread (lambda ()
                                (loop (sleep 0.1))))))
  (bt:destroy-thread thread)
  (print (bt:thread-alive-p thread))
  (print (bt:thread-alive-p thread))
  (print (bt:thread-alive-p thread)))`

I'm guessing destroy-thread only sends a kill signal, but it does not wait for the thread to die before returning. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

```
(bt:destroy-thread (nth index (bt:all-threads)))
```

It maybe be good the check if thread is alive, `(bt:thread-alive-p <thread>)` and not the current one, `(bt:current-thread <thread>)` Before killing it..

Comment: Thank you! I asked mostly because I am trying to port [The Common Lisp Cookbook - Threads](http://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/process.html) from Lispworks to Bordeaux-Threads, and adding how to filter the thread list is probably a good idea.